# How do I fix "cannot be sent between threads safely" when using tokio::spawn and Box<dyn Error>?

Tags: rust, thread-safety, rust-tokio, trait-objects

This simple program yields a compiler error:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    tokio::spawn(async {
        foo().await;
    });
}

async fn foo() {
    let f1 = bar();
    let f2 = bar();

    tokio::join!(f1, f2);
}

async fn bar() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    println!("Hello world");
    Ok(())
}
```

```
error[E0277]: `(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:5:18
    |
5   |       tokio::spawn(async {
    |  _____------------_^
    | |     |
    | |     required by a bound introduced by this call
6   | |         foo().await;
7   | |     });
    | |_____^ `(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely
    |
    = help: the trait `Send` is not implemented for `(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)`
    = note: required for `Unique<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>` to implement `Send`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Box<dyn Error>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `MaybeDone<impl Future<Output = Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>>>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `(MaybeDone<impl Future<Output = Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>>>, MaybeDone<impl Future<Output = Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>>>)`
    = note: required because it captures the following types: `ResumeTy`, `impl Future<Output = Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>>`, `(MaybeDone<impl Future<Output = Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>>>, MaybeDone<impl Future<Output = Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>>>)`, `&mut (MaybeDone<impl Future<Output = Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>>>, MaybeDone<impl Future<Output = Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>>>)`, `u32`, `[closure@join.rs:95:17]`, `PollFn<[closure@join.rs:95:17]>`, `()`
note: required because it's used within this `async fn` body
```

I don't really understand what the error means. When I remove the return type of the `bar` function it works, but what is the actual error here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Box<dyn Error>` is an opaque type. It may contain any type.

Suppose it contains a type that cannot be safely send to a different thread than the one it was created in. For example, a `MutexGuard`, that must release the mutex when dropped from the same thread as it acquired it. Or an `Rc`, that decrements the reference count on drop non-atomically, and thus can cause a data race on drop if moved to another thread. Then we should not send it to another thread. We say *the type does not implement [`Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Send.html)*. Because `Box<dyn Error>` may contain such types, it itself does not implement `Send`.

However, `tokio::spawn()` may move the future between threads between `.await` points. This is to improve efficiency: `tokio` uses a *work-stealing* scheduler, meaning it will move tasks to threads (and therefore CPU cores) that are less busy. But suppose the `Box<dyn Error>` would contain a type that does not implement `Send`, for example `MutexGuard`, it would be created before the `tokio::join!()` call, in thread A, and dropped after it, potentially in thread B! (because `tokio::join()` has an implicit `.await`). This mean this is not safe, therefore the future of `foo()` is not `Send` either, and you cannot spawn it into a task.

The fix is simple: ensure the `Box<dyn Error>` is `Send`. This can be done by adding a `+ Send` bound to it:

```rust
async fn bar() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send>> {
    println!("Hello world");
    Ok(())
}
```